# I cannot add new folder at res directory

Tags: android, eclipse, android-layout

> I need to create folder at res this folder has sound but i couldn't and i don't whey ?

[image]

Comment: Call that folder `raw` I have it

Comment: you can't name it as you want, there is specific naming convention for them ( like raw )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We must create a **`raw`** folder and then add your mp3

[image: raw folder]

**You access to your file that way :**

```
getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.sound);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your mp3 file should be added to res/raw (you may need to create this). Good luck !