# Try to read text file in Android return ENOENT (No such file or directory) error

Tags: android

I'm trying to read a text file that is present on the "Res" folder of the project in Eclipse. For do it i'm using this method that i call in my main activity.

```
public String findString() throws java.io.IOException{
    String line;
    String result = "";
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(this.getResources().getString(R.xml.start_config)));
    while( ( line = reader.readLine() ) != null)
    {
        result += line;
    }
    reader.close();
    return result;
}
```

The text fileis "start_config.txt". I'm not understanding why the Logcat is returning to me this error when the method is called.

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /res/xml/start_config.txt: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

I have read some questions similar here in stack overflow but without success. Am i missing something in my code? Is there something wrong? I'm not understanding.

Update: now i can read the text file but seems that not all chars are showed correctly.
In fact if for example that text file is:

```
<configuration>
  <products currency="EUR">
    <product id="1" width="1794" height="1204" name="10 X 15 cm">
      <prices>
        <price fixfee="0.5" from="20" price="0.60" />
        <price fixfee="0.10" from="10" price="0.70" />
        <price fixfee="0.10" from="0" price="0.80" />
      </prices>
    </product>
```

The result seems actually is something like:

```
10 X 15 cm??prices??fixfee??from??price??0.5??20??0.60??0.10??10??0.70??0??0.80??2??3599??2396??
20 X 30 cm??0.90??1.00??3??2100??1499??
13 X 18 cm??0.75??4??2549??
15 x 21 cm??5??1062??
9 X 13 cm??0.50???????$??????????????????????????????????????????????????8????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????t???????????????????????????????????????????????????? ??????????????????????????
```

What can i do? Have i to encode it? Or the problem is another?

Thanks

Comment: What's the value of this.getResources().getString(R.xml.start_config))?

Comment: Try to store files in raw folder and read from there.

Comment: @AsierAranbarri the value is /res/xml/start_config.txt

Comment: @ShabbirDhangot the raw folder need to be created inside the res folder?

Comment: Yes it is inside res folder

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Code for read file from raw folder

```
InputStream iStream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.profit_lost);

txtContent.setText(readTxt());
```

readText Function()

```
private String readTxt()
{
     ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
     int i;
     try 
     {
         i = iStream.read();
         while (i != -1)
         {
             byteArrayOutputStream.write(i);
             i = iStream.read();
         }
         iStream.close();
     }
     catch (IOException e) 
     {
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
     return byteArrayOutputStream.toString();
}
```

I am getting Perfect Result at myside

[image]

Comment: thanks for help. I can read the text file now but seems that not all chars are correctly show. Please see my question i have updated it. Thanks

Comment: I test your file in my app Its working perfectly. May be some problem with your reading method.

Comment: in fact now i'm using your method. The only thing that is missing is that i don't have put the file inside the raw folder because i don't have it inside the res folder

Comment: create raw folder in res.. right click res -> new -> folder -> give folder name `raw` ..

Comment: thanks for help! Now it works correctly! I'm not understanding now why if i create a folder with another name it doesn't work. Which is the logic about this?

Comment: I think you need to read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17260310/i-cannot-add-new-folder-at-res-directory

Comment: thanks. In fact i have created without problem a folder called xml, so i don't understand what's the problem. Probably there is a convention about the names that need to be used in the folders of the projects.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50005/discussion-between-shabbir-dhangot-and-hieicker)